# Microsoft Cognitive Speech to Text

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

The documentation, and other help links provided by microsoft suggests to use VS2015.

I have a project built in .net framework 4.0 using VS2010 in WPF. And I want to implement the speech to Text functionality in my project.

> Note: I can't upgrade to VS2015 and would like to implement the
>   microsoft cognitive speech to text functionality using VS2010.

Is this possible and please do explain if it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Have you tried something that didn't work? Cognitive Services is a REST API that can be called from any language. It's just common sense that you should use the latest version, especially when it's free. Also, .NET 4.0 is no longer supported, 4.5.2 is a binary replacement which means that your machine and your clients' probably uses 4.5.2 already.

Comment: Yes, I did try to port the code to .Net 4.0 and the same using VS2010 but I didn't succeed in that. As you said, I think I'll have to use the 4.5 framework and may be a newer version of visual studio.

Comment: Port what code? It's a REST API, all you need to call it is WebClient or HttpWebRequest, although you'd have to handle authentication and generating the correct URLs yourself. The SDK and proxies though are written in .NET 4.5.

Comment: I'm trying to use the client library and I tried to use the code presented in github and the link which I'm referring to is https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpDesktop   pl do guide me if I got it all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think VS2015 is a requirement (though I'm not 100% sure). My team recently added a sample speech-to-text bot in github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText, which shows how you can convert an audio file that the user uploaded to text. You can easily port the code to a WPF app (note that the sample is available in C# and node.js). Check it out and let us know if it worked.

Comment: thank you for replying and will let you know of the progress made.

Comment: one question though, instead of using using an audio file, can i use the mic instead (i.e. record the audio from mic what the user is saying and then display the same)?

Comment: Yes, the Speech API supports audio streaming as explained in the documentation (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#SpeechService). The example I sent is using an audio file as input as messaging channels don't support sending audio streams to bots. But, you can easily change the input to the API to be streaming audio.